# Laravel deleting polymorph relations having possibly wrong relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism, eloquent

I have a model that represents a report from a user. The report model has a polymorphic relationship which can contain either a recipe or a comment.

The goal is to be able to delete a comment or user and have the related reports removed by eloquent.

With my current setup (seen below) this does not work, when deleting a comment the report remains and causes an error since it now points to a non-existing comment.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a "belongsTo" relationship on my polymorphic model? If so how do I build this relationship when the relation is morphable?

---

### Models

Polymorphic Model

```
class Report extends Model {
    public function reportable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Recipe Model

```
class Recipe extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function reports() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
    }
}
```

Comment Model

```
class RecipeComment extends Model {   
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function reports() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel doesn't have anything built in to automatically delete related records. You need to build this functionality yourself, which can be done using Model events. Typically, I setup a `deleting` event that takes care of deleting the related records inside a transaction.

A Laravel 5 [model observer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers) would look something like this:

```
class RecipeCommentObserver {
    public function deleting($model) {
        try {
            DB::transaction(function() use ($model) {
                /**
                 * Try to delete the necessary related objects when this object is deleted.
                 */

                // detach the many-manys from this model, which will delete
                // the records in the pivot table.
                // e.g. if you had a many-many relationship named 'tags':
                // $model->tags()->detach();

                // the one-one and one-many relations to try and delete
                // for your example, you probably only want 'reports' here.
                // you probably don't to delete the user when deleting a comment.
                $relations = ['reports'];

                foreach ($relations as $relation) {
                    // get a list of all the related ids for this relation
                    $ids = $model->$relation()->lists('id');

                    // use the ->destroy method so any events get fired for the deleted objects
                    // if the amount deleted is less than expected, an error occurred
                    if (!empty($ids) && $model->$relation()->getRelated()->destroy($ids) < count($ids)) {
                        throw new Exception('Error occurred deleting ' . $relation);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

With this class setup, you register the observer in the `boot()` method in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events) {
    parent::boot($events);

    RecipeComment::observe(new RecipeCommentObserver());
}
```